# why there is no response on level 0,1 in ajax (onreadystatechange)

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is my code,i don't know why case 0, and case 1 are not working?
are there any responses for these levels?

This is the output

- request received
- processing request
- request finished and response is ready!

```js
        var xhr = false;
        function checkAJAXSupport() {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
              xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
              try {
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              } 
              catch (e) {
                try {
                  xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } 
                catch (e) {}
              }
            }
         if (!xhr) {
              alert("your browser is very outdated!");
         
     window.location.href = "http://www.google.com?q=download firefox";
            }
        }
  checkAJAXSupport();
  
 

  function sayHello(id, msg, time) {
   var target = document.getElementById(id);
   var text = document.createTextNode(msg);
   var br=  document.createElement("br");
   setTimeout(function() {
   target.appendChild(text);
   target.appendChild(br); 
   }, time)
   
  }
  
  
  xhr.open('GET','sidebar.html',true);
  var sec = document.getElementsByClassName('sec');
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   switch(xhr.readyState) {
    case 0: console.log("Request Not Initialized");break;
    case 1: console.log("Server connection Stablished");break;
    case 2: sayHello('ajax','request received',200);break;
    case 3: sayHello('ajax','processing request',400);break;
    case 4: sayHello('ajax','request finished and response is ready!',600);break;
   }
  }
  xhr.send();
```

```html
<section id="sec" class="sec">
 <p id="ajax">
 </p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your handler doesn't receive `0` (`UNSENT`) because there's no state change (0 is the initial state), so the handler is not called. You also don't receive `1` (`OPENED`) because you assign the handler after you open the request. Put the handler before the `.open` call if you want to be notified when the request is opened:

```
    xhr.onreadystatechange = ...
    xhr.open('GET','sidebar.html',true);
```

Comment: You actually will receive a 0 state because calling open resets the state property. It doesn't matter if the value is the same as before, the ready state has received a new value.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: that's new to me. Could you make a snippet/fiddle that demonstrates this behaviour?

Comment: Please see my code snippet in my answer for the XHR response codes and you will see why you will see a 0 if you place the callback hook up prior to open. You can refer to this as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @ScottMarcus: when I run your snippet I see "send has not yet been called but open has been called" in my console, followed by a cross-origin error.

Comment: Yes, that's just because we're here in SO. Give me a sec to work on an example that you can run.

Comment: Check out this page and click the "load remote data" button. http://techtrainsolutions.com/so/ajax.html with your console open. The file doesn't use jQuery, just good old-fashioned JS.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: 404 not found ;(

Comment: @georg on nginx-php(fcgi) server the states 2,3 and 4 are called altogether i.e. when content is sent by server ( i have seen this by adding a sleep 0f 15 second on the very first line of server side script )

Answer (score 2):

**You had your readystatechange callback AFTER you had already opened the XHR.** Moving that to BEFORE will allow you to see all the readystates.

```js
var xhr = false;
        function checkAJAXSupport() {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
              xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
              try {
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              } 
              catch (e) {
                try {
                  xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } 
                catch (e) {}
              }
            }
         if (!xhr) {
              alert("your browser is very outdated!");
         
     window.location.href = "http://www.google.com?q=download firefox";
            }
        }
  checkAJAXSupport();

  function sayHello(id, msg, time) {
   var target = document.getElementById(id);
   var text = document.createTextNode(msg);
   var br=  document.createElement("br");
   setTimeout(function() {
   target.appendChild(text);
   target.appendChild(br); 
   }, time)
   
  }
  
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
         /*
         XMLHttpRequest.readyState Codes:
         ================================
         0 = open has not yet been called
         1 = send has not yet been called but open has been called
         2 = send has been called but no response from server
         3 = data is in the process of being received from the server
         4 = response from server has arrived
        */
   switch(xhr.readyState) {
    case 0: console.log("open has not yet been called");break;
    case 1: console.log("send has not yet been called but open has been called");break;
    case 2: sayHello('ajax','send has been called but no response from server',200);break;
    case 3: sayHello('ajax','data is in the process of being received from the server',400);break;
    case 4: sayHello('ajax','response from server has arrived!',600);break;
   }
  }
  
  xhr.open('GET','sidebar.html',true);
  var sec = document.getElementsByClassName('sec');

  xhr.send();
```

```html
<section id="sec" class="sec">
 <p id="ajax">
 </p>
</section>
```

If you move the code that sets up the callback for readystatechange to **BEFORE** you open the XHR, you will see a complete progression, from 0 to 4, but you had already opened your XHR BEFORE you hooked up the callback.

Comment: Thank you guys!
i have another stupid question : in case 0 or 1 when i use sayHello() function it return (firefox console) "TypeError: target is null", why?

Comment: What values are you passing to `sayHello()` because the variable `target` in that function (that the error is telling you is null) comes from finding the element in the DOM whos id is the `id` attribute you pass in.